# Testar método de acesso, se é GET ou POST

Tags: php

Estou tendo problemas com a inserção de dados em meu formulário. O problema envolve o mecanismo de transação do meu formulário, exibindo a mensagem de erro do `die` antes mesmo de carregar a página.

Meu orientador disse que o problema ocorre porque o código está sendo executado diretamente sem nenhum tratamento. Disse também que isso seria resolvido colocando todo o código dentro de uma função, só o chamando caso o método de acesso fosse `POST`.  Para tal, seria feito um teste, onde seria testado se o método de acesso fosse `GET` ou `POST`, caso seja `GET` exibiria o formulário normalmente, caso fosse `POST` seria chama a função que trata do cadastro.

Como seria feito esse testo do método de acesso?

Segue o código que trata do cadastro nos formulários:

```
<?php
//CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
include_once("conexao.php");

function cadastrar(){
    //VARIÁVEIS COM DADOS DO FORMULÁRIO
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $senha = $_POST["senha"];
    $senhaConfirm = $_POST["senhaConfirm"];
    $telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
    $celular = $_POST["celular"];
    $rua = $_POST["rua"];
    $bairro = $_POST["bairro"];
    $numero = $_POST["numero"];
    $cidade = $_POST["cidade"];
    $estado = $_POST["estado"];
    $cep = $_POST["cep"];
    $complemento = $_POST["complemento"];
    $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
    $nomeMercado = $_POST["nomeMercado"];
    $cnpj = $_POST["cnpj"];
    $telefoneMercado = $_POST["telefoneMercado"];
    $celularMercado = $_POST["celularMercado"];
    $expedienteInicio = $_POST["expedienteInicio"];
    $expedienteFim = $_POST["expedienteFim"];
    $arquivo = $_POST["arquivo"];

    //INICIO DA TRANSAÇÃO
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    //INSERÇÃO DE DADOS NA TABELA ENDEREÇO
    $insertEndereco = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ENDERECO(BAIRRO, CEP, CIDADE, COMPLEMENTO, ESTADO, NUMERO, RUA) VALUES(:bairro, :cep, :cidade, :complemento, :estado, :numero, :rua)");  
    $insertEndereco->bindValue(':bairro',$bairro);
    $insertEndereco->bindValue(':cep',$cep);
    $insertEndereco->bindValue(':cidade',$cidade);
    $insertEndereco->bindValue(':complemento',$complemento);
    $insertEndereco->bindValue(':estado',$estado);
    $insertEndereco->bindValue(':numero',$numero);
    $insertEndereco->bindValue(':rua',$rua);
    $testaInsertEndereco = $insertEndereco->execute();
    //VERIFICA SE A INSERÇÃO DE DADOS DE ENDEREÇO RETORNA TRUE(FOI REALIZADA)
    if (!$testaInsertEndereco) {
        die("Oops, houve um erro no cadastro de seu endereço, tente novamente ou contacte a adaministração.");
    }
    $cod_endereco = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    //INSERÇÃO DE DADOS NA TABELA USUARIO
    $insertUsuario = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO USUARIO(TIPO_USUARIO, NOME_USUARIO, E-MAIL_USUARIO, SENHA_USUARIO, CELULAR, COD_ENDERECO, TELEFONE) VALUES (:usuario,:nome,:email,:senha,:celular,:cod_endereco,:telefone)"); 
    $insertUsuario->bindValue(':usuario',$usuario);
    $insertUsuario->bindValue(':nome',$nome);
    $insertUsuario->bindValue(':email',$email);
    $insertUsuario->bindValue(':senha',$senha);
    $insertUsuario->bindValue(':celular',$celular);
    $insertUsuario->bindValue(':cod_endereco',$cod_endereco); 
    $insertUsuario->bindValue(':telefone',$telefone);
    $testaInsertUsuario = $insertUsuario->execute();
    if (!$testaInsertUsuario) {
        die("Oops, houve um erro no cadastro de seus dados pessoais, tente novamente ou contacte a adaministração.");
    }
    $cod_usuario = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    //INSERÇÃO DE DADOS NA TABELA SUPERMERCADO
    $insertMercado = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO SUPERMERCADO (CNPJ, NOME, FOTO_SUPERMERCADO, INICIO_EXPEDIENTE,                 
        FIM_EXPEDIENTE, TELEFONE) VALUES (:cod_endereco_mercado, :cod_usuario, :cnpj, :nomeMercado, :arquivo, :expedienteInicio, :expedienteFim, :$telefoneMercado)");
        $insertMercado->bindValue(':cod_endereco_mercado',$cod_endereco);
        $insertMercado->bindValue(':cod_usuario',$cod_usuario);  
    $insertMercado->bindValue(':cnpj',$cnpj);
    $insertMercado->bindValue(':nomeMercado',$nomeMercado);
    $insertMercado->bindValue(':arquivo',$arquivo);
    $insertMercado->bindValue(':expedienteInicio',$expedienteInicio);
    $insertMercado->bindValue(':expedienteFim',$expedienteFim);
    $insertMercado->bindValue(':telefoneMercado',$telefoneMercado);
    $testaInsertMercado = $insertMercado->execute();
    //CASO TENHA DADO ALGUM ERRO NA TRANSAÇÃO rollBack IRÁ CANCELAR TODAS ELAS
    if (!$testaInsertMercado) {
        die("Oops, houve um erro no cadastro de seu mercado, tente novamente ou contacte a adaministração.");
            $pdo->rollBack();
    }
    //FINALIZANDO TRANSAÇÃO
    $pdo->commit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

O teste seria algo como:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{    //faça algo...
```

Comment: Fiz da seguinte forma:

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  cadastrar();
 }

       function cadastrar(){
                /*códgio que trata dos cadastros*/
       }
Porém a página não carrega, dando erro no php.

Comment: qual erro apresenta ?

Comment: Bom, não fui muito específico no erro, na verdade o erro ocorre quando eu submeto os dados do formulário, isto é, aperto em cadastrar.
O erro é o HTTP ERROR 500.

Answer (score -4):

O certo seria fazer esse tratamento igual na resposta acima, ou (se sua lógica de negócios permitir), você pode simplesmente colocar `$_REQUEST['nome_parametro']`, que ele irá pegar POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, etc...

Comment: Por que deram -3 na minha resposta?